# How to get XYZ data of room center?

Tags: c#, plugins, revit-api

I am trying to place an element into the center of several rooms. So far I have achieved something similar by using the Location Point which has placed the element close to the center but not exact.

I attempted to fix this by using two methods that I believed would help accomplish this task, GetElementCenter and GetRoomCenter but when I run the plugin, nothing happens.

```
class Class2
{
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        //Get access to Revit command data, user interface and document
        UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
        UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        //Collect all rooms
        FilteredElementCollector roomCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(SpatialElement));

        // Collect element
        FilteredElementCollector element = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FamilySymbol)).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Cameras);

        //Get symbol
        FamilySymbol elementSym = element.FirstElement() as FamilySymbol;

        using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc))
        {
            try
            {
                tx.Start("Start");

                //For loop for every room in the roomCollector 
                foreach (SpatialElement oneRoom in roomCollector)
                {
                    //Get area of each room
                    Room room = oneRoom as Room;
                    double area = room.Area;

                    //Location point version
                    Location loc = room.Location;
                    LocationPoint location = loc as LocationPoint;
                    XYZ point = (null == location) ? XYZ.Zero : location.Point;

                    //New version
                    XYZ source = GetRoomCenter(room);

                    double smallRoom = 301;
                    
                    if (area <= smallRoom)
                    {
                        doc.Create.NewFamilyInstance(source, elementSym, Autodesk.Revit.DB.Structure.StructuralType.NonStructural);
                    }
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Print(e.Message);
                tx.RollBack();
            }
        }
        TaskDialog.Show("Message", "Task completed successfully");
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    public XYZ GetElementCenter(Room room)
    {
        BoundingBoxXYZ bounding = room.get_BoundingBox(null);
        XYZ center = (bounding.Max + bounding.Min) * 0.5;
        return center;
    }
    public XYZ GetRoomCenter(Room room)
    {
        XYZ boundCenter = GetElementCenter(room);
        LocationPoint locPt = (LocationPoint)room.Location;
        XYZ roomCenter = new XYZ(boundCenter.X, boundCenter.Y, locPt.Point.Z);
        return roomCenter;
    }
}
```

}

Any help on getting the XYZ data of the center of a room would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have straight walls bounding the room, I would suggest that you take a look at mathematical and geometrical algorithms for determining the [center point of a polygon](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=polygon+center+point). Something like this [new algorithm for finding a visual center of a polygon](https://blog.mapbox.com/a-new-algorithm-for-finding-a-visual-center-of-a-polygon-7c77e6492fbc) is probably best suited to your needs, even though you neither state this fact nor probably are yet aware of it :-)

Comment: I took a look at the links you sent and did some research, I found that the ComputeCentroid method might be useful. Although it is based on Solids which doesn't seem to work with Room elements, do you know if there is a way to use ComputeCentroid for Room elements?

Comment: You can query a room for a solid representing its volume using its ClosedShell property: https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/1a510aef-63f6-4d32-c0ff-a8071f5e23b8.htm. However, that is a 3D method. I think a 2D method would be far more suited to your needs, and much more efficient.